# Dynamically connecting oracle database through Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, postgresql

From my few days of learning Ruby on Rails i understood that the database configuration has to be made in database.yml file. But my requirment is i have to work with 2 different database.

I will be getting few user profile information and his/her oracle database connection information (SID, user name, password) from user. And i will be storing them in postgresql db. The stored information of user will be listing  on dashboard. when a user clicks on that listed records then the application should fetch the oracle connection details form postgresql database and connect to that particular oracle database and it should show me the tables available on the oracle database.

is it possible with ROR 4?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a whole lot of personal experience with this gem, but I've heard it recommended for this exact scenario it's called [octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus), there's a link to the github repo